# Request to make tag [jung2] a synonym of [jung]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[jung2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jung2) and [jung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jung) both relate to the JUNG Java graph library, of which I am one of the co-creators and primary maintainer.

There's no particular reason why [jung2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jung2) needs to exist as a separate tag at all, in fact.  Assuming that we can't just retag everything with [jung2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jung2) as [jung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jung), it would make it much easier for people asking and answering questions about JUNG if anything that was tagged with [jung2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jung2) would also get tagged [jung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jung).

Comment: mm... 70 questions with jung2, 24 without jung. I'm not sure we need the synonym. We can in a flash just retag everythin.

Comment: I don't think that we do need the synonym; if we can just retag everything, I'm just fine with that solution.  (I don't know if there's a way to discourage redundant tags from being (re-)created, but that's a separate problem.)

Comment: I should clarify: if we can tag everything that's [jung2] as [jung] and then delete [jung2], that's fine.  Just retagging everything without deleting the [jung2] tag seems much less useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to manually retag anything here, I added [jung2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jung2) as a synonym for [jung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jung). That is:

[jung2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jung2) (× 90) → [jung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jung) (× 430)

I'll merge the tags in a few days, just to make sure that there are no issues with the synonym. And finally, it definitely is nice to see maintainers of the actual libraries come forward and post tag synonym requests on meta, so thank you for that.

Comment: Thank you!  Documentation and discoverability are important, so I appreciate your help in getting this sorted out.  :)